# Hide / Disable ListView Column (Not width=0 Hack)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

We are redesigning our Listviews to allow the user to select columns he want to have displayed.

In order to not mess around with a `Key-To-Column-Index` Conversion when filling up the listview, we would like to maintain a "basic" order of columns, then use the display-index and (?) the visible-attribute on certain columns to adjust the view.

i.e. the basic table looks like

```
id | name | date
```

it's filled with data like

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Text = someObject.ID;
lvi.SubItems.Add(someObject.Name);
lvi.SubItems.Add(someObject.Date);
...
ListView1.Items.AddRange(CollectionOfListViewItems);
```

If the user now selected the display order `id | date | name`, this can be easily achieved (without modifying the code that generates the ListViewItems) by simply changing the displayindex value of a certain column.

However, if the user wants to exclude a column, there is the common practice to set the width to 0. But this leads to the unnice behaviour, that people that trying to extend any column sometimes just expand a column with width 0 and are confused whats going on.

Is there a way to properly hide a column from being displayed, without actually removing the column from the listview? (Cause removing the column would require adjustments to the generating code, else Headers / values are no longer correctly aligned).

Comment: Use `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I've now extended the `width=0` hack with the - let's call it - `displayIndex=0` hack. Works like a charm:

**Iteration 1**: We keep adding the columns as per our definition, so we don't need to refactor any code that relies on that column order:

```
foreach (ColumnDefinition cd in this.ColumnDefinitions)
{
    ColumnHeader ch = new ColumnHeader();
    ch.Name = cd.Name;
    ch.Tag = cd;
    ch.Text = cd.Text;

    this.extendedListView.Columns.Add(ch);
}
```

**Iteration 2**: To respect the users displaly-order, we modify the `displayIndex` as mentioned above, as soon as all columns are added to the listview:

```
foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.extendedListView.Columns)
{
    //DisplayIndex known?
    if (keyToIndex.ContainsKey(ch.Name))
    {
        int idx = keyToIndex[ch.Name];
        ch.DisplayIndex = idx;
    }
}
```

Note: Columns the user has deselected don't have an display index stored in the configuration. So they now are floating around somewhere (with width 0), leading to the problem that they could be extended, when trying to extend another column.

**Iteration 3**:To overcome that issue, we just iterated another time, and pushed every invisible column to index 0. *No User should ever try to resize a column by clicking on the left side of the left-most column visible*:

```
//Avoid inivisble columns (width 0) beeing stuck somewhere in between. 
//push them all to the front, cause no one will try to expand the "0st Column".
foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.extendedListView.Columns)
{
    //DisplayIndex not known?
    if (!keyToIndex.ContainsKey(ch.Name))
    {
        ch.DisplayIndex = 0;
        ch.Width = 0;
    }
}
```